# New Certification Logos

Tags: discussion

It's not like it has a major impact on my life or anything, but am I the only one that thinks the new certification logos that came out today are a bit....blah?

I don't know, its not as though I think they are poorly done, or terrible, I was just a bit underwhelmed.  Am I being too critical of something that really doesn't matter??

Just curious others thoughts.

[image]

[image]

Maybe it's just that I liked they at least had some sort of difference between the different types (red for admin, blue for dev) before.  They are identical besides the text.

Comment: Poor design i think, arrrgghhh!

Comment: Well I am glad I'm not the only one who thinks so

Comment: It looks like they are following Apple with their flat icons in iOS7 but Im glad they dropped the "No Software" bit.

Comment: I just got certified at DF and yes I think the new logos suck!

Comment: @sfdc_ninja  agreed! I think a sub-icon identifying the area of specialism/expertise would be useful & nice.

Comment: Does this mean the "No Software" is going away?  What will become of Saasy???

Comment: I actually heard Benioff refer to Salesforce as a software company during his DF13 keynote! They needed to get rid of their "No Software" branding for the longest time. Hopefully Saasy will be taken out and shot (JK!)